# How to use base64 in highcharteR in R?

Tags: r, r-highcharter

Let's say we have the following matrix:

```
m <- matrix(1:12, 3, 4, dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:4]))
```

and we plot that using highcharteR:

```
library(highcharter)
hchart(head(m, -1), "bubble", hcaes(),
       showInLegend = FALSE)
```

we could than replace the labels of the x-axis by images, e.g. for A:

```
hchart(head(m, -1), "bubble", hcaes(),
       showInLegend = FALSE) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(type = 'category',
           labels = list(
             formatter = JS(
               "function(){
                  if(this.value == 'A'){
                    return '<img src=\"https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png\"></img>';
                  } else {
                    return this.value;
                  }
               }"
             ),
             useHTML = TRUE
           ))
```

That will give us:[image: a picture of the highcharter output]

**But how do we get the same result with base64 instead of url? Is there any way to embedd the image within the html highcharteR produces?**

I tryed converting the image to base64 and embedding it into the chart:

```
image_path <- "https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png"
image_data <- base64enc::dataURI(file=image_path, mime="image/png")


hchart(head(m, -1), "bubble", hcaes(),
       showInLegend = FALSE) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(type = 'category',
           labels = list(
             formatter = JS(
               sprintf(
                 "function(){
                    if(this.value == 'A'){
                      return '<img src=\"%s\"></img>';
                    } else {
                      return this.value;
                    }
                 }",
                 image_data
               )
             ),
             useHTML = TRUE
           ))
```

But that gives me no image. The output is blank and html (in the output) at this position is just: `<img>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that highcharts.js is verifying the html produced by such functions as
`labels.formatter`. In particular, the `src` attribute has to start with one of
the values contained in `Highcharts.AST.allowedReferences`, see that in
the [source code](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/v9.3.1/ts/Core/Renderer/HTML/AST.ts#L171).

A simple solution would be to set the `src` separately, immediately after the
current javascript sequence of instruction is completed, using `setTimeout`. That
means replacing

```js
return '<img src=\"%s\"></img>';
```

with

```js
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('img_data1').src = '%s'}, 0);
return '<img id=\"img_data1\"></img>';
```

A more canonical solution would be to alter `Highcharts.AST.allowedReferences`
by adding `"data:"` as an allowed prefix.  While that can be done in the
`formatter` itself:

```js
function(){
    if(this.value == 'A'){
        if(Highcharts.AST.allowedReferences.indexOf('data:') === -1){
            Highcharts.AST.allowedReferences.push('data:')
        }
        return '<img src=\"%s\"></img>';
    } else {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

it would be more efficient to do the change to `allowedReferences` only once,
for instance by [prepending](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/htmlwidgets/html/prependContent.html)
that javascript statement to the htmlwidget produced by highcharter (or by other
initialization hooks specific to your application):

```R
library(highcharter);
library(htmlwidgets);
library(htmltools);

m <- matrix(1:12, 3, 4, dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:4]))
image_path <- "https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png"
image_data <- base64enc::dataURI(file=image_path, mime="image/png")

initCode <- HTML("<script>Highcharts.AST.allowedReferences.push('data:')</script>")

hchart(head(m, -1), "bubble", hcaes(),
       showInLegend = FALSE) %>% 
  prependContent(initCode) %>%     
  hc_xAxis(type = 'category',
           labels = list(
             formatter = JS(
               sprintf(
                 "function(){
                    if(this.value == 'A'){
                      return '<img src=\"%s\"></img>';
                    } else {
                      return this.value;
                    }
                 }",
                 image_data
               )
             ),
             useHTML = TRUE
           ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I love your solution and it works like a charm. Also thank you very much for your explanation!